# Как получить текст из TextView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Как получить текст из `TextView` при нажатии на элемент из `RecyclerView`, к примеру ввожу сумму и при нажатии на элемент из `RecyclerView` Сумма сохраняется в строку как  `название нажатого элемента + сумма из TextView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в адаптере переопределив метод onClick получил имя элемента, но как получить сумму из `TextView` не знаю

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + personName.getText());

    }
```

текст суммы вставляю следующим кодом, а как сюда добавить название элемента из `RecyclerView`

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String last = textView_sum.getText().toString();
    if (v.getTag().toString().equals("C")) {
        if (!last.equals("")) {
            last = last.substring(0, last.length() - 1);
            textView_sum.setText(last);
        }
    } else {
        last += v.getTag().toString();
        textView_sum.setText(last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что за сумма и в чём конкретно проблема - не понятно. Попробуйте чётче сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, есть поле первое `введите сумму` к примеру ввел 100 и нажал на элемент из `RecyclerView` и нужно это сохранить в строку к примеру `String temp = введенная сумма + название нажатого элемента из RecyclerView`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы можете помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно берите `TextView` и формируйте нужную строку:

```
String temp = textView.getText().toString() + personName.getText();
```

Comment: так не получается сделать, вылезает NPE ошибка

Comment: @java тогда хоть пример кода покажите, как-то же Вы забиваете туда сумму, значит так же нужно и брать

Comment: код активити нужно показать или?